# Здравствуйте, подскажите про json

Tags: python, json

Короче в json ответе от сервера может стоять значение ключа json а может и не стоять.
В итоге python первые значения показывает, а потом когда ключа нету, выдает ошибку и прекращает работу. А мне надо чтобы просто пропускалось если нету значения.

```
data = response.json()
# Узнаем кол-во друзей
count = data['response']['count']
print(f"Количество друзей: \n{count} \n")

print("Дата пользователя ")
for item in data['response']['items']:
            print(item['bdate'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса не совсем понятно, какие именно объекты являются опциональными. Вот надёжное решение:

```
data = response.json()
# Узнаем кол-во друзей
try:
    count = data['response']['count']
    print(f"Количество друзей: \n{count} \n")
except KeyError:
    pass

try:
    for item in data['response']['items']:
        print(f"Дата пользователя\n{item['bdate']}")
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Готов ответить на вопросы :)

Comment: а через item.get('bdate')?

Answer (score 0):

Так как `data = response.json()` возвращает словарь

```
print(type(data))

<class 'dict'>
```

Вы можете, при получении значений, использовать метод [get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), который при отсутствии ключа возвращает значение по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0):

Можно прямо проверять наличие ключа через `in`:

```
for item in data['response']['items']:
    if 'bdate' in item:
        print(item['bdate'])
```